# How to pass a table-row value to the servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a table which has certain attributes and a button in the last column of each row.

```
         <tr>
            <td>B001</td>
            <td>The Catcher In The Rye</td>
            <td>199</td>
            <td><select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            </select></td>  
            <td><button>Add To Cart</button></td>           
        </tr>
```

I have to get the entire row value in id, name, price, quantity respectively in the Servlet I am using. How do I do that?

Using forms we do something like -

```
String name = request.getParameter("LoginName");
```

But there is no id here for the table. So how to achieve the same so that I can retrieve a particular row's values?

Comment: You should read about [*forms*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put some hidden fields inside your page to carry selected row data.

Set those hidden fields with the clicked row data using javascript when button is clicked.

And submit the form.

try this http://jsfiddle.net/LBJWQ/7/

This is JSP & Servlets 101. You should be reading up on HTML and Javascript as well.

Comment: and then how to retrieve in the Servlet? String id = request.getParameter("item");

Comment: Yes i forgot about that. http://jsfiddle.net/LBJWQ/8/ check now. Give same values for the "id" and "name" attributes of hidden fields. Now you can access like `String something = request.getParameter("row_id");` etc.